# Can I define an identifying relationship with an artificial PK

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I have several models in my project which really should be using identifying relationships, but I have them setup with unique auto-increment primary keys for speed and simplicity reasons.  For example, email addresses in a contact:

```vb
Public Class EmailAddress
    'This is currently the primary key
    Public Property EmailAddressID As Integer

    'These three properties really make a composite primary key in an identifying relationship with contacts
    Public Property ContactID As Integer
    Public Property Address As String
    Public Property Domain As String
End Class
```

I have two questions about this setup:

1. Does having `nvarchar` field(s) inside a composite key really slow down the DB enough to warrant not using it (as I was led to believe in school)?
2. If yes to 1, is there a way (either in Data Annotations or the Fluent API) to inform EF that this is actually an identifying relationship with an artifical primary key and thus [reap the benefits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373856%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (under heading "Considerations for Identifying and Non-identifying Relationships")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. Keys are a logical, data integrity feature; performance depends on many other things.
2. In the relational model and in SQL the distinction between an identifying and non-identifying relationship is of very little or no importance at all. You may find such terms helpful as a way of understanding a conceptual model but they are not really a sound basis for making database design decisions. The alleged "benefits" you refer to are essentially just syntactic sugar.

Comment: The model already is, as far as I understand, an identifying relationship conceptually, it's just not defined that way in the DB.  If EmailAddress is definitely a 100% dependent child of Contact (I would not want an EmailAddress to exists without a Contact), is there any reason *not* to change my DB schema to reflect this?